# Strip words from Woocommerce product attributes at checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have attributes on all of my products such as "Select your size" and "Select your colour", however in the basket and at checkout I would like to strip "Select your" from all of the attributes so that it is not displayed.

*As shown on product page:*
[image: As shown on product page]

*As currently shown at checkout, however I really want to remove "Select your":*
[image]

Is there an easy way to do this in the Woocommerce template files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fighting away with this will be a battle of the century... you will not just have to remove that string in there... it will also be like that on the email sent and order page will display it. Also some pages I can't remember...

I think you just want the "Select your" string in the product page, is it not?

if so, why not add that string just in there?
So in your variation, in the product admin page, add the variation as `size`. Then change the display in product page like this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_attribute_label','reigel_attribute_label', 10, 2);
function reigel_attribute_label( $label, $name ) {
    if (is_product() && $label == 'size') {
        $label = 'Select your ' . $label;
    }
    // another if statement if needed...
    if (is_product() && $label == 'color') {
        $label = 'Select your ' . $label;
    }
    return $label;
}
```

with this approach, you will just have the `Select your size` in the product page...

Comment: Thanks for this, I'm assuming I would just repeat the code for each variation that I want to append "Select your" to?

Answer (score 1):

You can use WooCommerce's in build API function to do both.
eg. 
1. Returns a specific item in the cart.

```
get_cart_item( $item_key );
```

https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#751-762

2.Process the checkout after the confirm order button is pressed.

```
process_checkout();
```

https://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#343-718

You can take all the reference you need. There are lists of functions are available to do changes.

Comment: Thanks Vivekanand, although I don't want to play too much I really just want to strip the words "Select your"